# Single noun for "based on the previous experience with them"?

Tags: word-choice

I have a sentence like this:

> I've chosen them based on the previous experience I had with them.

Now is there any noun that I can use to replace the last part of the sentence?

Comment: If you want to pack a noun, an adjective, a preposition, two pronouns, and a verb in a single noun, you should try Newspeak rather than English.

Comment: So I'm relatively new to this site and I'm not sure how the voting system is working here. So it would be nice if you could explain the down votes. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest there is no single noun - nor any other single word - for that.

If you think there is, what close or even vague suggestions have your dictionaries, therauruses or search engine come up with - or is this too special to have similarities?

Answer (score 1):

And answer came there: None.<sup>1</sup>

You could possibly replace "the previous experience I had with them" with *prior experience.*  Although it's slightly ambiguous, the context and the use of *prior* would imply "with them".

> I've chosen them based on prior experience.

I don't think there's a way to express "prior experience" in one word and retain the "with them" aspect.

---

<sup>1</sup> after [Lewis Carroll](http://www.jabberwocky.com/carroll/walrus.html) (misquoted!)

Comment: Experience tends to be prior, at least in my experience.

Comment: Well, you could be dealing with the supplier in question at the moment, so *current* experience in that context isn't the same as prior experience.

Answer (score 0):

I've **consciously/knowingly** chosen them.

> consciously¹: in a conscious manner; knowingly, volitionally.
>
> knowingly¹: in the manner of one who knows, with knowledge of all
>   relevant facts.

These words can convey the meaning of "based on the previous experience I had with them", depending that from the context.

¹ Wiktionary.

Comment: I don't agree with "Consciously." To choose them consciously just means I was aware when I was making a choice, but does not mean  I had prior experience. As for knowingly, I think that "choosing knowingly" means I know what will come of my choice (but not necessarily because of prior experience with "them").  This is a tough question; and I don't think there is really any perfect answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could get away with saying "I chose them empirically" (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empirically)

"a posteriori" is another term that could capture the essence of "based on the previous experience with them."  (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aposteriori).

However, "a posteriori" is usually used to qualify knowledge or the act of knowing, so this application would be a stretch. (http://www.iep.utm.edu/apriori/).

Comment: Why the down-vote? I'm new to this, so if I have blundered, I would love to know what I did wrong.

Comment: I haven't voted on your answer and likewise wonder why it got 2 downvotes.  Suggestion "I chose them empirically" looks perfectly ok.  Here are some of my reasons for not upvoting: • Irrelevant reference to German • Unsupported assertion "there is no single word that..." • Reference to "that thought" even though question did not express a particular thought • Lack of definitions (or links to defs) for *empirically* and *a posteriori*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback jwpat7. I have made changes to improve the quality of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it flows better if you start with 'choice'.

*My choice (of them) was based on experience*

Or you could continue a previous sencence, if it is not too long:

*..., my choice being based on experience.*

Answer (score 0):

How about "history"?

> I've chosen them based on my history with them.

It explains that you chose them based on previous experience and the context is sufficiently clear that you don't need to declare that it was a good experience.  You wouldn't have selected them had you had bad experiences.

Answer (score -1):

You could conceivably say **extrapolatively**, meaning that you're extrapolating from your past experience with them how they are likely to perform in the future.